# Getting error related to permission trying to pull docker image from Google Artifact Registry via Container-Optimized OS VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-build

I am trying to use Cloud Build using Google cloud to pull and run an image on `Container-Optimized OS` VM compute engine
In my cloudbuild.yaml I have

```
steps:

  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
    args:
      - compute
      - ssh
      - --zone
      - "us-central1-a"
      - $_SSH_STRING
      - --project
      - $PROJECT_ID
      - --
      - docker pull us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/us/$_IMAGE_NAME:latest &&
      - docker run -d -p 1338:1338   us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/us/$_IMAGE_NAME:latest
```

I run `gcloud builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml .`
getting this error

```
Error response from daemon: Head "https://us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/v2/myProjectId/us/imageName/manifests/latest": denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource "projects/myProjectId/locations/us-central1/repositories/us" (or it may not exist)
```

I am sure that the `PROJECTNUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com` has `Artifact Registry Reader` and I even tried to give it `Artifact Registry Administrator` role. More over I made a custom role where it has `artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts` added

Still can't make it to work and I get the same error
I also SSH to the VM and tried to run it manually and still the same error about permission. I don't know what more permission I can grant

PS: I am sure the image exists

**EDIT:**

The error occurs within the VM after Cloud Build establishes an SSH connection to it. This error is not caused by Cloud Build itself, but rather by the permissions of the VM's compute engine "Which as I siad above, I already made sure that the service account has the right roles and permissions". Furthermore, this error can occur not only when using the Container-Optimized OS but also when running an Ubuntu OS. The only difference is that in Ubuntu OS, you have the option to install Google Cloud SDK and run the 'gcloud credentials helper' like this `gcloud auth configure-docker $_ARTIFACT_ZONE-docker.pkg.dev`.

Comment: The issue is that you are running Docker inside Cloud Build. This is not related to `Container-Optimized OS`.

Comment: Thanks for answering. If it is related to cloudbuild, then I also tried to give the cloud build service account Artifact Registry Reader permission. But even if I SSH directly to the machine that I am trying to pull and run the image on it, I still can't pull the image and get the same error.

Comment: You are trying to pull an image at two different resources: Cloud Build and Compute Engine. You are testing one to try and solve the other. Focus on Cloud Build first. Why are you using Docker to pull and run an image in Cloud Build (as a step)? Create a new question for Compute Engine COS as that is a different problem with a different solution.

Comment: Thanks John for the follow up. When I talked about ssh into the Compute Engine I meant it as debug step to see if the error also happens when I try the same command that cloud build excute after it ssh to VM via gcloud `docker pull us-central1-docker.pkg.dev/$PROJECT_ID/us/$_IMAGE_NAME:latest`. You are right the problem not from the Cloud Build. The problem that the VM doesn't have permissions. And that's my question, why I am getting the error even though the service account has the Artifact Registry Reader role and should have the permissions to excute that command and I said that in the Q

Comment: One more note. If I use a VM with Ubuntu OS which means I can install Google Cloud SDK and run gcloud credentials helper like this `gcloud auth configure-docker $_ARTIFACT_ZONE-docker.pkg.dev` it works. But i can't do it with container optimized OS VM. But if I don't run gcloud credentials helper I get the same error even in Ubuntu VM. 100% permission problem with VMs in Compute Engine as said even though I added the required role and permissions `Artifact Registry Reader`

Comment: COS loads one image that you specify as part of the VM configuration. You do not run images manually. If you want to run images via Docker, then use Compute Engine and not Compute Engine Optimized OS. The two services appear similar but have very different security models enforced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki for everyone's visibility.

Container-optimized OS loads one specified image as part of the VM configuration. If running images via docker is what you want, then you should use [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute) and not [Container-optimized OS](https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/concepts/features-and-benefits). The two services appear similar but have very different security models enforced.